# haskell load data from 'script' file

Tags: haskell

I have been reading "learn you haskell for great good", and in this part:

"let’s put a string that represents a person in a script and then load that script in GHCi:

```
mysteryDude = "Person { firstName =\"Michael\"" ++
                      ", lastName =\"Diamond\"" ++ 
                      ", age = 43}"
```

We wrote our string across several lines like this for increased readability. If we want to read that string, we need to tell Haskell which type we expect in return:

```
ghci> read mysteryDude :: Person
```

But I don't know how to create the 'script', it's in mysteryDude.hs file, and then I need to load it with `>:l mysteryDude.hs` 
Or what. But I tried it and I got this error:

```
*Main> read mysteryDude.hs :: Person

<interactive>:50:23: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Person’
*Main> read mysterDude.hs :: Person
```

I see that in the web [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters), they change it, and don't do it in the same way, so, maybe it's an error.

But even if in this example is an error I would like to know how to write a 'script' and load data from it.

Comment: Did you define `data Person` inside `mysteryDude.hs`?

Comment: No, it's in another file, in person.hs

Comment: Does `mysteryDude.hs` import it?

Comment: no... I starting to see the problem

Answer (score 2):

From comments I deduced the problem. `:l` in ghci forgets all previous `:l`s and all definitions that you made in REPL. You should either:

- Make files import each other (avoiding import cycles). Filenames and module names must match.
- `import` both files in ghci. Again, module names should match the names of files.
- Make all your definitions in REPL's toplevel. You may use multiline snippets surrounding them by `:{ :}`. Not recommended tho